# Javascript Chrome vs Edge in my ASP.NET Web Api project. Chrome passing null

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api

When I try to update my employee then it passes null Gender and Department with Chrome, but not with Edge. With Edge it's working fine.

My html bootstrap page:

```
<label for="Gender">Gender</label>
 <select id="Gender" class="form-control">

  </select>

<label for="Department">Department</label>
<select id="Department" class="form-control">

 </select>
```

In my java page I begin with this below in the top of the page.

```
setInterval(function () {

    loadEmployee();

}, 500);



function loadEmployees() {


    $.ajax({
        url: "/Api/Computers",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + item.EmployeeId + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.EmployeeName + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + item.Gender + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + item.Department + '</td>';
        html += '<td><Button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return getEmplyeeByID(' + item.EmployeeId + ')">Edit</button></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            });
            $('.tbody').html(html);
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}

// To retrieve Gender and Departments in dropdown list
function Departments() 
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Api/Departments",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
           $.each(result, function (key, value) {
$("#Department").append($("<option></option>").val(value.DepartmentId).html(value.DepartmentName));
});
        }
    });

}

function Gender() 
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Api/Genders",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
           $.each(result, function (key, value) {
$("#Gender").append($("<option></option>").val(value.GenderId).html(value.GenderName));
});
        }
    });

}
function getEmplyeeByID(EmployeeId) {
      Departments();
      Gender();

     $('#EmployeeId').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
     $('#EmployeeName').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
     $('#Gender').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
     $('#DepartmentName').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Api/Employees/" + EmployeeId,
        typr: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {

            $('#EmployeeId').val(result.EmployeeId);
            $('#EmployeeName').val(result.EmployeeName);
            $('#Gender').val(result.Gender); // retrived from select option javascript
            $('#Department').val(result.Department);// retrived from select option javascript

            $('#btnUpdate').show();

        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

And finaly my Update function

```
function Update() {

    var EmployeeId = $('#EmployeeId').val();
    var CusObj = {

        EmployeeId: $('#EmployeeId').val(),
        EmployeeName: $('#EmployeeName').val(),
        GendertId: $('#Gender').val(),
        DepartmentId: $('#Department').val(),

    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Api/Employees/"+EmployeeId,
        data: JSON.stringify(CusObj),
        type: "PUT",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        //dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {

            loadEmployees();


            $('#myModal').modal('hide');

            $('#EmployeeId').val("");
            $('#EmployeeName').val("");
            $('#Gender').val("");
            $('#Department').val("");

        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

But both Departments and Gender are passing null in Chrome When I try to update employee but not using Edge. When I use Edge then passes value, but using in chrome.. value of gender and departments are null. I know it must be something with Jquery.. Can you please guys help me what's I'am doing wrong and how I can correct my code? Thank you in Advance!

Comment: This won't answer your question directly but it will show you that your code works on chrome and IE https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/r0qmqmxj/ You need to find out why it is failing on CHROME, do you have any error on the console?

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 Thank man. It's working now fine with after I added  $('#Departments').on('change',function(){
 Departments();

}); ans the same to gender .... Thank you again!

Comment: Glad it helped!